# IOS App with non-public selectors can be accepted by Apple?

Tags: validation, app-store, iphone-privateapi

I use voluntarily a private Apple API in my code.
Just as I feared, I Archived and validated my app with the following warning:
**/!\ the app references non-public selectors  in Playload ...**

To give more explanation, I use the private API  to access to the avplayer of a UIWebView. Then, I'm able to manage this player in background without any user interactions! (I have any other solution)

What are the risks to be rejected? 
It is possible to be accepted with a warning like this one?
It is smart (or not at all) to try to submit it?

Comment: I've never tried, but I guess you can't even submit the app with such a warning.

Comment: I just tried... My app is uploaded (ever with warning) ,i's work, now i'm waiting... I'm freaking out ^^

Comment: You could try obfuscating the usage of this selector.  At a minimum, make sure the name of the private selector isn't visible if you run the `strings` command on your executable.  Indirection based on methods in [the ObjC runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) might also increase your chances of getting it through review.

Comment: The app has been accepted!

Comment: How long have you had the APP in Appstore? Have you been forced to take it down, or it still lives in AppStore?

Comment: I'v not yet release the app, but it has been accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, my application has been accepted by Apple and available on the app store. So if you're not in a hurry, you can try! (but it's not recommended)